# How to handle click events on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a data set of items coming from a SQL database. Those items are displayed in multiple divs like:

```
 <?php
 $url = 'DataBase';

 $json_response = file_get_contents ( $url );

 $json_arr = json_decode ( $json_response, true );

 for($i = count ( $json_arr )-1; $i > 0;  $i--) {
 $json_obj = $json_arr [$i];


 echo '<div id="MyDIV">';
 echo $json_obj ['id'] ;
 echo $json_obj ['title'];  
 echo $json_obj ['article'];  
 echo '<button id="read_more_btn">Read more</button>';
 echo '</div>'
 }
 ?>
```

My problem is that I cannot handle click events for EACH div, so I cannot identify which item has been clicked. I’ve been searching for a solution for quite a while, but haven’t found anything. So my question is – how can I identify the clicked item?

**EDIT**
I have no idea how I can dynamically assign an ID to a button

Comment: what do you mean by `I cannot handle click events for EACH div, so I cannot identify which item has been clicked.` As in it doesnt work? or you cant figure out how to find out which div has been clicked?

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context, that's why...

Comment: I cant figure out how to find out which div has been clicked

Comment: You show us php code for a problem with... click events? Could you please post the relevant code?

Comment: post your javascript code as well with the exact issue you are facing. additionally, a jsfiddle (with html output from php) would help.

Comment: ***+bis*** IDs **must*** be unique on document context, that's why whatever you try to bind click event, is wrong!

Comment: @A.Wolff I updated my question. I don't know how to achieve this

Comment: Instead of `id="MyDIV"` & `id="read_more_btn"` use class and bind event to class. You should find many example on the web

Comment: what does `$json_obj['id']` contains for each element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `data` attributes (HTML5 assumed) to attach the Id as meta data to your `div`s. Your PHP (note I am adding `data-id` attributes):

```
<?php
 $url = 'DataBase';
 $json_response = file_get_contents ( $url );
 $json_arr = json_decode ( $json_response, true );
 for($i = count ( $json_arr )-1; $i > 0;  $i--) {
   $json_obj = $json_arr [$i];
   echo '<div data-id="' . $json_obj['id'] . '">';
   echo $json_obj ['id'] ;
   echo $json_obj ['title'];  
   echo $json_obj ['article'];  
   echo '<button id="read_more_btn">Read more</button>';
   echo '</div>'
 }
 ?>
```

JS - simple click handler attachment, using jQuery `.data()` [[docs]](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to get data attribute:

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    alert(id);
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vyfk76fL/)

Comment: Make sure you concatenate with `.` instead of `+` in PHP

Answer (score 2):

How about when creating the html in the php, you echo the id inside the class.
`echo '<div id="mydiv-' . $json_obj['id'] . '">';`

So now in the html, it's going to look like
`<div id="mydiv-1"> ... </div>`
`<div id="mydiv-2"> ... </div>`
`<div id="mydiv-3"> ... </div>`
etc.

And then in Javascript, you could access them the same way you access any tag.

```
$('#mydiv-1').click(function(e){
    console.log('a div was clicked');
    console.log($(this))
});
```

So in order to assign listeners to each `div`, you could do a loop

```
for(var i = 1;$('#mydiv-container').children().length >= i,i++)
{
     $('#mydiv-' + i).click(function(){ 

}
```

Make sure to add a container for all the divs.

Answer (score 1):

Give each div a unique numeric class, so your jquery will be

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("class");
    //do stuff here
});
```

or

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var item_id = this.className;
    //do stuff here
});
```